# How to get the current Facebook page ID for canvas iframe app?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, facebook

I've got a Rails app that's running in an iframe in a canvas app for a page.

What I need to do is get the current page ID to pass to the iframe.

Basically trying to have the iframe show X based on what page the app is setup on.

Comment: I find this question a little unclear. First, is the 'canvas app' also your code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As described in [Page Tab Tutorial](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/appsonfacebook/pagetabs/):

> When a user selects your Page Tab, you will receive the `signed_request` parameter with one additional parameter, page. This parameter contains a JSON object with an `id` (the page id of the current page), `admin` (if the user is a admin of the page), and `liked` (if the user has liked the page). As with a Canvas Page, you will not receive all the user information accessible to your app in the `signed_request` until the user authorizes your app.

Comment: Gotta love em' signed_requests ;)